# Oracle SQL updating HUGECLOB

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I am using TOAD (11.0 R2) for Oracle.

I need to update one of the columns in a table that holds data of type NCLOB.  My UPDATE statement looks like this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET    string_content = 'SELECT my_string FROM table2 WHERE name = 'identifier''
WHERE  id = 10000
```

The problem is with the `'` around the word `identifier` in my SELECT statement. The `'` that immediately preceeds the word `identifier` ends the string.

I hope there is just a simple syntax error that I need to correct.  Can someone show me how I can get the above statement to work please?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Use two single quotes `''`

```
UPDATE table1
SET    string_content = (SELECT my_string FROM table2 WHERE name = ''identifier'')
WHERE  id = 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be this one:

```
UPDATE table1
SET    string_content = 'SELECT my_string FROM table2 WHERE name = ''identifier'''
WHERE  id = 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
UPDATE table1
SET    string_content = 'SELECT my_string FROM table2 WHERE name = ''identifier'''
WHERE  id = 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you can use a function for quoting string literals. It treats anything in the exclamation marks like a string literal. No need to double quote. [Link for reference](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=311)

```
DECLARE
    var_Updated_sql CLOB := q'!SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE name = 'aName';!';
BEGIN
    UPDATE fakeTable SET sqlStatement = var_Updated_sql WHERE sql_id = 1;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like double quoting and you are using Oracle >= 10g you can use quote operator `q` (more info [here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=311)):

```
UPDATE table1
SET string_content = 'SELECT my_string FROM table2 WHERE name = ' || q'['identifier']'
WHERE  id = 10000
```